# Profile values between a certain number in a matrix

Tags: matlab

I am working on a hobby project where I have a matrix 1x1000 with numbers such as 0 30 50 70 100 50 60 0 50 40 30 20 50 0 and so on.

Now I would like to profile all the values in between the 0, so in my example above it would result in [30 50 70 100 50 60] and [50 40 30 20 50]. I have tried `range` but that is probably not the right way to go.

Furthermore, I would like to set a condition that it can only profile if there is a certain amount of numbers between the zeros, for instance 5.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: what do you mean "profile"

Comment: I want to plot these profiles later on so something that can be saved, doesn't really matter how. Also interested in the indices so I don't want them excluded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use find to locate to non-zero numbers. Then find the start and end index of the different segments.

```
% Example input
A = [0 30 50 70 100 50 60 0 50 40 30 20 50 0];

% Find start and end point of segments
validIdx = find(A(:)~=0);
idxEdge = diff(validIdx) > 1;
fromTo = [ validIdx([true ; idxEdge])  validIdx([idxEdge ; true]) ];

% Create segments
C = arrayfun(@(from,to) A(from:to), fromTo(:,1), fromTo(:,2),'UniformOutput',false);
```

The `arrayfun`at the end could be replaced by a `for`loop to speed up the evaluation

```
C = cell(length(A),1);
for k = 1:size(fromTo,2)
    C{k} = A(fromTo(k,1):fromTo(k,2));
end
C(cellfun('isempty',C)) = [];
```

Giving:

```
celldisp(C)
C{1} =
    30    50    70   100    50    60 
C{2} =
    50    40    30    20    50
```

To find the segments of a certain minimun length (for example all segments larger than 5)

```
% Get the length of each segment
nNumbers = cellfun(@length, C);
lengthThreshold = 5;
% Remove shorter segments
C = C(nNumbers > lengthThreshold);
```

Giving:

```
celldisp(C)
C{1} =
    30    50    70   100    50    60
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will use this in a script, when I run this I get "Not enough input arguments". The error is caused by @(from,to) numbersMat(from:to). In my case A is replaced with numbersMat.

Comment: I've updated my code to work for both row and column vectors. Also added an my example vector `A`

Comment: I tried it out and get: Error using vertcat Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not consistent. This line gives the error: fromTo = [ validIdx([true ; idxEdge])  validIdx([idxEdge ; true]) ];

Comment: Is your input variable a matrix of size 1xN as stated in the question. Or does it differ from the form/class that `A` has in my example?

Answer (score 3):

I think that in this case a simple loop is the best solution:

```
V = randi(10,500000,1)-1 %random vector generation
V = [0;V;0]; %need to start and end with 0
pos = find(V==0); %find the 0's position
for i = 1:length(pos)-1
    M{i} = V(pos(i)+1:pos(i+1)-1);
end

ind = cellfun(@length,M);
M(ind<5) = [];
```

Comment: True, simpler! Only drawback is that it assume that V should begin and end with an 0, but that seems to be the case in this question (voting up)

Comment: @nilZ0r Thanks to highlight this problem ! It's corrected now

Comment: Instead of `floor(rand(500000,1)*10)` just use `randi(10,500000,1)-1`, it's quicker...

Answer (score 1):

Here is another option that does the follows:

1. Does not assume the vector starts and ends with `0`.
2. Can handle series of `0` within the vector.
3. Eliminates empty cells from the output.
4. Preallocate the output, and loop only on the segments that are above the predefined size

```
minsize = 5; % minimum size for segment
V = (randi(10,50,1)-1)*10; % random vector generation
zero_pos = find([0;V(:);0]==0); % all 0's position
d = diff(zero_pos); % count how large is each segment
% Ignore 0 and <minsize sized segments:
seg_start = zero_pos([true;d>max(minsize,1)])-1;
segments = cell(numel(seg_start)-1,1); % preallocate segments array
for k = 1:numel(seg_start)-1
    segments{k,1} = nonzeros(V(seg_start(k)+1:seg_start(k+1)-1)).';
end
```

and a typical input (`V`) and output(`segments`):

```
V =
  Columns 1 through 12
    70     0    60    40    40    10    10    10    20    90    70    20
  Columns 13 through 24
    90    60    10     0    20    60    10    10     0    40    70    90
  Columns 25 through 36
     0    30    80     0    30    10    40    60    30    60    50    30
  Columns 37 through 48
    40    10    10    80    80     0    10    20    40    50    20    50
  Columns 49 through 50
    90    80

segments{1} =
    70
segments{2} =
  Columns 1 through 12
    60    40    40    10    10    10    20    90    70    20    90    60
  Column 13
    10
segments{3} =
    20    60    10    10
segments{4} =
    40    70    90
segments{5} =
    30    80
segments{6} =
  Columns 1 through 12
    30    10    40    60    30    60    50    30    40    10    10    80
  Column 13
    80
segments{7} =
    10    20    40    50    20    50    90    80
```

Comment: Awesome, I will try it out. Just a question, if I run it with a script I would like to save the output somehow so I can display everything later. Is there any way to put this cells into a array or similar?

Comment: It's already in a [`cell array`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/create-a-cell-array.html), you can't put unequal sized arrays within a matrix.

Comment: I tried it out, it seems to work except that it miss the last number before every 0. Any suggestions?

Comment: @J.Smith I can see what you mean, it works right for me. Can you give an example for an input vector that don't work?

Comment: It seems that zero_pos = find([0;V;0]==0); is the problem, as it it giving me "Error using vertcat Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not consisten". Forgot to mention it but I tried zero_pos = find([0;myVector(:);0]==0); instead and it works but miss one number before each 0.

Comment: @J.Smith That's not seems to be the problem. Even if I define `V` as a row, and then write `zero_pos = find([0;V(:);0]==0);` I get the correct answer. Please give an explicit example (as small as possible) for a vector that doesn't work.